# VHDL SCROLL WORLD ON 7-SEGMENT DISPLAY

Tags: vhdl

For the first eight seconds after the system has been reset, the FSM inserts the correct characters (H,E,L,L,O, , , ) into the first of the 7-bit registers in the pipeline. After step 1 is complete, the FSM configures the pipeline into a loop that connects the last register back to the first one, so that the letters continue to scroll indefinitely every second. Your circuit should scroll the word "HELLO" such that the letters move from right to left. Scrolling should continue indefinitely; after the word "HELLO" scrolls off the left side of the displays it should start again on the right side.

hello,I don't understand how can I connect the registers in a pipeline and how to define the FSM's states.
can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? The assignment appears to be derived from the Altera University Program Laboratory Exercises for the DE2 (found oddly enough on the v.0.3 DE1 CDROM). It would be common modify the exercises for university courses and Laboratory Exercise 7 was dumbed down before the v2.0.2 CDROM for DE2.

Comment: [Laboratory Exercise 7](http://hamblen.ece.gatech.edu/DE1/DE1_CDROM/DE1_lab_exercises/DE2_labs_vhdl/lab7_VHDL.pdf) Part V "Design your circuit by using eight 7-bit registers connected in a queue-like fashion, such that the outputs of the first register feed the inputs of the second, the second feeds the third, and so on. This type of connection between registers is often called a *pipeline*." Part VI "Write VHDL code in the style shown in Figure 3 for your finite state machine, and ensure that all flip-flops in your circuit are clocked directly by the CLOCK_50 input." (See Part II.)

Comment: part6.vhd code found in PDF pages 111-113 of [Laboratory Exercise 1 Switches, Lights, and Multiplexers](https://www.academia.edu/24416132/Laboratory_Exercise_1_Switches_Lights_and_Multiplexers) (which includes Exercises 1 - 9) implements your assignment although the counter does not have an accurate one second interval and uses a latch to distinguish between inserting the correct characters and recirculating. The document is [also available on Yumpu](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/53370945/laboratory-exercise-1) and [on Manualzz](https://manualzz.com/doc/6616271/brown-de2-labs).